# How to redirect user if not authentication on firebase

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to redrect user to login page if not auth my issue I cant see my code running if the user isnt auth,

```
userRoute.$inject = ['Router','$rootScope', '$state'];

function userRoute(Router,$rootScope,$state) {
    $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeError", function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, error) {
        // We can catch the error thrown when the $requireSignIn promise is rejected
        // and redirect the user back to the home page
         debugger;
        if (error === "AUTH_REQUIRED") {
            $state.go("login");
        }
    });
```

and on my route I did:

```
 controller: 'list.controler',
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    resolve: {
        "firebaseUser": function (authService) {
            // If the promise is rejected, it will throw a $stateChangeError
            return authService.firebaseAuthObject.$requireSignIn();

        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$state.go("login"); //

.state("login", {
    url:"/login",
    controller: "loginCtrl",
    templateUrl: "my/path/login.html"
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Id advice you to use your moduleName.run() function in your js file whether is was app.js or another file name , it would be look like that :

```
//your moduleName and it's dependencies here 
  .run(["$rootScope", "$state", function($rootScope, $state) {
      $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeError", function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, error) {
        // We can catch the error thrown when the $requireSignIn promise is rejected
        // and redirect the user back to the login page
        if (error === "AUTH_REQUIRED") {
          return $state.go("login");
        }
      });
    }])
```

In your index.html

```
     <script src=".../angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
     <script src=".../stateEvents.js"></script>
```

You'll need also to make a state for login, something like that :

```
.config(['$routeProvider', '$stateProvider', function($routeProvider, $stateProvider) {
  $stateProvider.state('login', {
    name: 'login',
    url: '/login',
    templateUrl: 'login/login.html',
    controller: 'loginCtrl'
  })
}])
```